# How to specify max memory for clojure heroku app?

Tags: heroku, clojure

Running a clojure app on Heroku, I've specified this in my leiningen profiles.clj

`:jvm-opts ^:replace ["-Xms128m" "-Xmx350m" "-Xss512k" "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=150m"]`

And I'm running my worker with `lein trampoline run`

But, I get these errors currently:

`2015-06-20T14:38:14.652680+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-06-20T14:38:34.779145+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=552M(107.8%)
2015-06-20T14:38:34.779145+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-06-20T14:38:54.511927+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=552M(107.8%)`

Since 350+150=500, I'm expecting that my memory usage should be below the 512MB limit on Heroku.  Is there another max memory setting I need to add?

Comment: What did you end up using for your jvm-opts to resolve this? I'm running into the same issue but its not clear how you used the the comment below to resolve it, did you just reduce the Xmx by 50mb to count for the extra 50mb?

Comment: I ended up with the set of options here: https://github.com/rogerallen/tweegeemee/blob/master/project.clj#L15-L20  It has been a while, so I don't quite recall how I exactly figured this out...

Comment: Thanks, right now I'm trying out `-Xms100m -Xmx300m -Xss512k` which seems to have a good result so far, staying just below or at 500MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku is limiting your process memory, which is different from the memory allocated by the JVM. See for example:

[Why is my JVM process larger than max heap size?](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/entry/why_is_my_jvm_process_larger_t)

Comment: This is true. The JVM will usually require 50mb to even 100mb of additional process memory for OS heap (not JVM heap), native libraries, file handles, IO buffers, and more. You could try setting Xmx lower or `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` very low.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try, Diego & codefinger.  Hopefully a lower Xmx will do the trick.

Comment: FWIW, my case seemed to need 112MB of space for the process.

Comment: @RogerAllen What did you end up setting the jvm-opts to in order to resolve this for you? Running into the same issue, but its not clear to me what you did with the 112MB of space needed for the process. Thanks!